# How do I debug a segmentation fault in Python when loading a BERT model?

Tags: python, nlp, segmentation-fault

I am attempting to test out this [KeyBERT model](https://github.com/MaartenGr/KeyBERT). I am new to Python (much experience in R). I'm not sure how to debug this issue since the error message is so short. My question is, how do I debug this with such little information? Where to start?

I have a fresh install of Anaconda with Python 3.9.13:

```
Python 3.9.13 (main, Aug 25 2022, 18:29:29) [Clang 12.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
```

When attempting to initialize a KeyBERT model I get a segmentation fault error. I'm not sure what the next steps would be to debug this. I'm well-versed with R, but still new to Python so I don't have a toolbox of debug steps. Any thoughts about where to look first?

```
>>> from keybert import KeyBERT
>>> kw_model = KeyBERT()
zsh: segmentation fault  python
```

I've run it in a Jupyter notebook with the same results. The first time I used it, the models were downloaded (I expect succesfully?). But when attempting to initialize the model, I get this segfault.

Edited to add, I used faulthandler to get this output:

```
(base) user@place ~ % python -q -X faulthandler
>>> from keybert import KeyBERT
>>> kw_model = KeyBERT()
Fatal Python error: Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Segmentation faultThread 0x

00000002054742c0 (most recent call first):
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1568 in _load_from_state_dict
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 469 in load
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 473 in load
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 473 in load
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 475 in _load_state_dict_into_model
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 2517 in _load_pretrained_model
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 2326 in from_pretrained
zsh: segmentation fault  python -q -X faulthandler
```

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this issue. Steps

1. Reinstalled PyTorch using `conda`
2. I imported `torch` before importing `KeyBERT`

Runs successfully, no errors, output is as expected. Thanks for anyone that read this.